# Cannot Update GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have the codes up but when I try to update, it did not change anything. I am not sure where the problem went wrong

I have tried to change the index of email and others from 0-6 but when I use these index, everytime i tries to update, the email became UserID and so on.

Back End:
    protected void gvAccount_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    {

```
    GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)gvAccount.Rows[e.RowIndex];
    string UserID = gvAccount.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Values["UserID"].ToString();
    string Email = ((TextBox)row.Cells[1].Controls[0]).Text;
    string FirstName = ((TextBox)row.Cells[2].Controls[0]).Text;
    string LastName = ((TextBox)row.Cells[3].Controls[0]).Text;
    string Password = ((TextBox)row.Cells[4].Controls[0]).Text;
    string Point = ((TextBox)row.Cells[5].Controls[0]).Text;
    string Role = ((TextBox)row.Cells[6].Controls[0]).Text;

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE UserRegister set Email = '" + Email + "', FirstName = '" + FirstName + "',  LastName = '" + LastName + "', Password = '" + Password + "',Point = '" + Point + "',Role = '" + Role + "' WHERE UserID =" + UserID, con);
    con.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
    gvAccount.EditIndex = -1;
    FillGrid();
    }
```

There is no error message, but it just did not update anything. I am not sure if is the WHERE UserID = UserID problem. UserID is my primary key

Answer (score 0):

I think you've mistaken to take the value. For Excel I use like this:

```
string email= row[1].ToString();
string firstName = row[2].ToString();
string lastName = row[3].ToString();
string pass= row[4].ToString();
string point = row[5].ToString();
string role = row[6].ToString();
```

*Update

Something's wrong with your SQL, for the query try somethings like this:

```
string con = @"Data Source=myServerAddress;Initial Catalog=myDataBase Integrated Security=SSPI;
User ID=myDomain\myUsername;Password=myPassword;";
string comm = @"Update... SET... WHERE...";
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(comm, con);
Gridview.Databind();
```

Comment: I tried changing but still the same. In fact, when i remove the whole portion of my codes, is still the same nothing happen. Thus, idk where went wrong

Comment: Maybe your SQL things went wrong. I usually use dataSet to CRUD

Comment: i tried using your method, it just doesnt update the db. I can CRD but just not U. this is killing me

Comment: http://aspnet-with-c-sharp.blogspot.com/2011/02/insertupdatedelete-in-gridview-aspnet.html

I followed this. Hopefuly someone can tell me where the problem went wrong. It shows the message "Record Updated Successfully" but the database remains unchange